# Is ZeroMQ designed for one directional communication?

Tags: c++, multithreading, zeromq

Most examples and tests for ZeroMQ use the channels in one direction. Clearly, some ZeroMQ patterns can be used for two directional communication but does that comes with a performance cost?

I've created an example to illustrate how we planned to use ZeroMQ, fully asynchronous where both client and server can send requests/replies at any time, from any thread. I've tried to be as simple as possible, but please try to ignore lack of error handling and the shutdown process. **Please comment any other issues** with the code **that you may find**.

The client can be run in to ways, either synchronous, where is serialize the requests, or asynchronous, where it creates a separate thread to send off the requests as soon as possible. The requests are small, just a timestamp when the request was created and a simple string. The server recieves the request, add some more string data and simply returns the reply. The client then extracts the timestamp in the reply and calculates the Round Trip Time.

Now, when run in asynchronous mode, the send thread isn't done until nearly all replies has been received. **Why is this, I was expecting the separate send thread to finish much sooner?**

And the RTT time is rather high.

**In asynchronous mode**, the RTT can be improved alot by adding a **`sleep(1)`** for every 150 request - without loosing much time sending/receiving all messages. **Does this indicate that ZeroMQ isn't handling the queues efficient?**

**In synchronous mode**, the RTT is way lower but still pretty high for just handling one request which then affects the total throughput.

Example of output when run locally on Windows 8 workstation:

```
Send thread finished, 100000 requests sent in us=1047525  
Received 100000 replies, last 10000 took us=95440, averate RTT=36228  
Work thread finished, 100000 replies received in us=1077641
```

Below you find the code for both client and server.

TIA

Client code:

```
// ZMQClient.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <profileapi.h>
#include <atomic>
#include <handleapi.h>
#include <process.h>
#include "zmq.hpp"
#include <queue>


using namespace zmq;
using namespace std;

//#define SYNCHRONOUS

namespace
{
    LARGE_INTEGER ui64StartCounter, ui64StopCounter, Frequency;
    HANDLE g_zmqThread = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    HANDLE g_workThread = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    HANDLE g_sendThread = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    SRWLOCK g_queueLock;
    queue<message_t*> g_incomingQueue;
    HANDLE g_queueUpdated = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    bool g_runThreads = true;

    context_t g_context(1);

    const unsigned int g_numOfIterations = 100000;
    const unsigned int g_statisticsInterval = 10000;
}



static DWORD WINAPI ZmqThreadStatic(PVOID pThreadParameter)
{
    if (pThreadParameter == nullptr) return ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER;

    PCSTR connectionAddress = (PCSTR)pThreadParameter;
    socket_t sendSocket(g_context, ZMQ_PULL);
    sendSocket.bind("inproc://sendsocket");

    printf("Connecting to: %s\n", connectionAddress);

    zmq::socket_t clientSocket(g_context, ZMQ_DEALER);
    clientSocket.connect(connectionAddress);

    zmq_pollitem_t pollItems[] = {
        { sendSocket, 0, ZMQ_POLLIN, 0 },
        { clientSocket, 0, ZMQ_POLLIN, 0 }
    };

    message_t zMsgt;
    int more;
    size_t size = sizeof(more);
    while (g_runThreads)
    {
        zmq_poll(pollItems, 2, -1);

        if (pollItems[0].revents & ZMQ_POLLIN)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                sendSocket.recv(&zMsgt, 0);
                sendSocket.getsockopt(ZMQ_RCVMORE, &more, &size);
                clientSocket.send(zMsgt, more ? ZMQ_SNDMORE : 0);
                if (more == 0) break;
            }
        }
        if (pollItems[1].revents & ZMQ_POLLIN)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                clientSocket.recv(&zMsgt, 0);

                message_t* newMsg = new message_t;
                newMsg->move(&zMsgt);
                AcquireSRWLockExclusive(&g_queueLock);
                g_incomingQueue.push(newMsg);
                ReleaseSRWLockExclusive(&g_queueLock);
                SetEvent(g_queueUpdated);

                clientSocket.getsockopt(ZMQ_RCVMORE, &more, &size);
                if (more == 0) break;
            }
        }
    }

    clientSocket.close();

    printf("ZMQ thread finished\n");

    return NO_ERROR;
}

static DWORD WINAPI WorkThreadStatic(PVOID pThreadParameter)
{
    socket_t sendSocket(g_context, ZMQ_PUSH);
    sendSocket.connect("inproc://sendsocket");

    LARGE_INTEGER ui64StartCounter, ui64StopCounter, ui64TotalCounter, ui64RTTCounter, Frequency;
    QueryPerformanceFrequency((PLARGE_INTEGER)&Frequency);
    ui64TotalCounter.QuadPart = 0;
    ui64RTTCounter.QuadPart = 0;
    unsigned int iterations = 0;

#ifdef SYNCHRONOUS
    LARGE_INTEGER ui64CurrentCounter;
    printf("Work thread sending synchronous requests...\n");
    string dataStr = "Hello World, " + to_string(iterations);
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&ui64CurrentCounter);
    message_t outMsg(sizeof(ui64CurrentCounter) + dataStr.size());
    memcpy(outMsg.data(), &ui64CurrentCounter, sizeof(ui64CurrentCounter));
    memcpy((char*)outMsg.data() + sizeof(ui64CurrentCounter), dataStr.c_str(), dataStr.size());
    sendSocket.send(outMsg, 0);
#endif
    bool isWorking = true;
    while (isWorking && g_runThreads)
    {
        switch (WaitForSingleObjectEx(g_queueUpdated, INFINITE, FALSE))
        {
            case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
                while (!g_incomingQueue.empty())
                {
                    AcquireSRWLockExclusive(&g_queueLock);
                    message_t* msg = g_incomingQueue.front();
                    g_incomingQueue.pop();
                    ReleaseSRWLockExclusive(&g_queueLock);

                    if (iterations == 0)
                    {
                        printf("First request, starting timer...\n");
                        QueryPerformanceCounter(&ui64StartCounter);
                    }

                    QueryPerformanceCounter(&ui64StopCounter);
                    LARGE_INTEGER* sendTime = (LARGE_INTEGER*)msg->data();
                    ui64StopCounter.QuadPart -= sendTime->QuadPart;

                    ui64RTTCounter.QuadPart += ui64StopCounter.QuadPart;
                    delete msg;

                    if (++iterations % g_statisticsInterval == 0)
                    {
                        QueryPerformanceCounter(&ui64StopCounter);
                        ui64StopCounter.QuadPart -= ui64StartCounter.QuadPart;
                        ui64StopCounter.QuadPart *= 1000000;
                        ui64StopCounter.QuadPart /= Frequency.QuadPart;
                        ui64RTTCounter.QuadPart /= 10000;
                        ui64RTTCounter.QuadPart *= 1000000;
                        ui64RTTCounter.QuadPart /= Frequency.QuadPart;
                        printf("Received %d replies, last %d took us=%lu, averate RTT=%lu\n", iterations, g_statisticsInterval, ui64StopCounter.QuadPart, ui64RTTCounter.QuadPart);
                        ui64TotalCounter.QuadPart += ui64StopCounter.QuadPart;
                        ui64RTTCounter.QuadPart = 0;

                        QueryPerformanceCounter(&ui64StartCounter);
                    }
                    if (iterations >= g_numOfIterations)
                    {
                        isWorking = false;
                    }
#ifdef SYNCHRONOUS
                    else
                    {
                        string dataStr = "Hello World, " + to_string(iterations);
                        QueryPerformanceCounter(&ui64CurrentCounter);
                        message_t outMsg(sizeof(ui64CurrentCounter) + dataStr.size());
                        memcpy(outMsg.data(), &ui64CurrentCounter, sizeof(ui64CurrentCounter));
                        memcpy((char*)outMsg.data() + sizeof(ui64CurrentCounter), dataStr.c_str(), dataStr.size());
                        sendSocket.send(outMsg, 0);
                    }
#endif
                }
                break;

            default:
                isWorking = false;
                break;
        }
    }

    printf("Work thread finished, %d replies received in us=%lu\n", iterations, ui64TotalCounter.QuadPart);

    return NO_ERROR;
}

static DWORD WINAPI SendThreadStatic(PVOID pThreadParameter)
{
    socket_t sendSocket(g_context, ZMQ_PUSH);
    sendSocket.connect("inproc://sendsocket");

    LARGE_INTEGER ui64CurrentCounter, ui64StartCounter, ui64StopCounter, ui64TotalCounter, Frequency;
    QueryPerformanceFrequency((PLARGE_INTEGER)&Frequency);
    ui64TotalCounter.QuadPart = 0;

    printf("Send thread sending asynchronous requests...\n");

    unsigned int iterations;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&ui64TotalCounter);
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&ui64StartCounter);
    for (iterations = 0; iterations < g_numOfIterations; ++iterations)
    {
        string dataStr = "Hello World, " + to_string(iterations);
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&ui64CurrentCounter);
        message_t outMsg(sizeof(ui64CurrentCounter) + dataStr.size());
        memcpy(outMsg.data(), &ui64CurrentCounter, sizeof(ui64CurrentCounter));
        memcpy((char*)outMsg.data() + sizeof(ui64CurrentCounter), dataStr.c_str(), dataStr.size());
        sendSocket.send(outMsg, 0);

        if ((iterations + 1) % g_statisticsInterval == 0)
        {
            QueryPerformanceCounter(&ui64StopCounter);
            ui64StopCounter.QuadPart -= ui64StartCounter.QuadPart;
            ui64StopCounter.QuadPart *= 1000000;
            ui64StopCounter.QuadPart /= Frequency.QuadPart;
            printf("Sent %d requests, last %d took us=%lu\n", iterations + 1, g_statisticsInterval, ui64StopCounter.QuadPart);
            QueryPerformanceCounter(&ui64StartCounter);
        }

        if ((iterations + 1) % 150 == 0)
        {
//          Sleep(1);
        }
    }
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&ui64StopCounter);
    ui64StopCounter.QuadPart -= ui64TotalCounter.QuadPart;
    ui64StopCounter.QuadPart *= 1000000;
    ui64StopCounter.QuadPart /= Frequency.QuadPart;

    printf("Send thread finished, %d requests sent in us=%lu\n", iterations, ui64StopCounter.QuadPart);

    return NO_ERROR;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    QueryPerformanceFrequency((PLARGE_INTEGER)&Frequency);

    g_queueUpdated = CreateEvent(nullptr, FALSE, FALSE, nullptr);

    PCTSTR serverAddress = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : _T("127.0.0.1");
    PCTSTR port = argc > 2 ? argv[2] : _T("14767");
    wstring connectionAddress = _T("tcp://");
    connectionAddress += serverAddress;
    connectionAddress += _T(":");
    connectionAddress += port;
    string address = string(connectionAddress.begin(), connectionAddress.end());

    g_zmqThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(nullptr, 0, (unsigned int(__stdcall *)(PVOID)) ZmqThreadStatic, (void*)address.c_str(), 0, (unsigned *)nullptr);
    Sleep(20); // Allow the new thread to bind internal socket
    g_workThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(nullptr, 0, (unsigned int(__stdcall *)(PVOID)) WorkThreadStatic, nullptr, 0, (unsigned *)nullptr);
#ifndef SYNCHRONOUS
    Sleep(20); // Allow the new thread to bind internal socket
    g_sendThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(nullptr, 0, (unsigned int(__stdcall *)(PVOID)) SendThreadStatic, nullptr, 0, (unsigned *)nullptr);
#endif

    getchar();

    printf("Closing down...\n");

    g_runThreads = false;
    SetEvent(g_queueUpdated);
    CloseHandle(g_queueUpdated);
    g_queueUpdated = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;

    g_context.close();

    printf("Successfully shutdown.\n");

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Server code:

```
// ZMQServer.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <profileapi.h>
#include <atomic>
#include <handleapi.h>
#include <process.h>
#include "zmq.hpp"
#include <queue>


using namespace zmq;
using namespace std;

namespace
{
    HANDLE g_zmqThread = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    HANDLE g_workThread = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    SRWLOCK g_queueLock;
    queue< pair<string, message_t*> > g_incomingQueue;
    HANDLE g_queueUpdated = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    bool g_threadsRunning = true;

    context_t g_context(1);
    context_t g_localContext(0);

    const unsigned int g_statisticsInterval = 10000;
}



static DWORD WINAPI ZmqThreadStatic(PVOID pThreadParameter)
{
    socket_t incomingSocket(g_localContext, ZMQ_DEALER);
    incomingSocket.connect("inproc://backend");

    socket_t sendSocket(g_localContext, ZMQ_PULL);
    sendSocket.connect("inproc://sendsocket");

    zmq_pollitem_t pollItems[] = {
        { sendSocket, 0, ZMQ_POLLIN, 0 },
        { incomingSocket, 0, ZMQ_POLLIN, 0 }
    };

    printf("Starting to handle incoming and outgoing data...\n");
    unsigned int iterations = 0;
    message_t zMsgt;
    int more;
    size_t size = sizeof(more);
    while (g_threadsRunning)
    {
        zmq_poll(pollItems, 2, -1);

        if (pollItems[0].revents & ZMQ_POLLIN)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                sendSocket.recv(&zMsgt, 0);
                sendSocket.getsockopt(ZMQ_RCVMORE, &more, &size);
                incomingSocket.send(zMsgt, more ? ZMQ_SNDMORE : 0);

                if (more == 0) break;
            }
        }
        if (pollItems[1].revents & ZMQ_POLLIN)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                incomingSocket.recv(&zMsgt, 0);
                string strId(static_cast<char*>(zMsgt.data()), zMsgt.size());
                incomingSocket.recv(&zMsgt);

                message_t* newMsg = new message_t;
                newMsg->move(&zMsgt);
                AcquireSRWLockExclusive(&g_queueLock);
                g_incomingQueue.push(make_pair(strId, newMsg));
                ReleaseSRWLockExclusive(&g_queueLock);
                SetEvent(g_queueUpdated);

                incomingSocket.getsockopt(ZMQ_RCVMORE, &more, &size);
                if (more == 0) break;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("Stopped handling incoming and outgoing data.\n");

    return NO_ERROR;
}

static DWORD WINAPI WorkThreadStatic(PVOID pThreadParameter)
{
    socket_t sendSocket(g_localContext, ZMQ_PUSH);
    sendSocket.bind("inproc://sendsocket");

    LARGE_INTEGER ui64StartCounter, ui64StopCounter, Frequency;
    QueryPerformanceFrequency((PLARGE_INTEGER)&Frequency);

    printf("Starting to process requests...\n");

    unsigned int iterations = 0;
    while (g_threadsRunning)
    {
        switch (WaitForSingleObjectEx(g_queueUpdated, INFINITE, FALSE))
        {
        case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
        {
            AcquireSRWLockExclusive(&g_queueLock);
            while(!g_incomingQueue.empty())
            {
                pair<string, message_t*> pair_data(g_incomingQueue.front());
                g_incomingQueue.pop();
                ReleaseSRWLockExclusive(&g_queueLock);

                string in((char*)pair_data.second->data(), pair_data.second->size());
                delete pair_data.second;

                string out = in + " - Reply";
                // This code below doesn't work when several threads are used, since the id end up in one thread and the data in another...
                message_t outMsg(out.size());
                memcpy(outMsg.data(), out.c_str(), out.size());
                message_t id(pair_data.first.size());
                memcpy(id.data(), pair_data.first.c_str(), pair_data.first.size());
                sendSocket.send(id, ZMQ_SNDMORE);
                sendSocket.send(outMsg, 0);

                if (iterations == 0)
                {
                    printf("First request, starting timer...\n");
                    QueryPerformanceCounter(&ui64StartCounter);
                }

                if (++iterations % g_statisticsInterval == 0)
                {
                    QueryPerformanceCounter(&ui64StopCounter);
                    ui64StopCounter.QuadPart -= ui64StartCounter.QuadPart;
                    ui64StopCounter.QuadPart *= 1000000;
                    ui64StopCounter.QuadPart /= Frequency.QuadPart;
                    printf("Received %d requests, last %d took us=%lu\n", iterations, g_statisticsInterval, ui64StopCounter.QuadPart);

                    QueryPerformanceCounter(&ui64StartCounter);
                }

                AcquireSRWLockExclusive(&g_queueLock);
            }
            ReleaseSRWLockExclusive(&g_queueLock);
            break;
        }
        default:
            g_threadsRunning = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    sendSocket.close();

    printf("Stopped processing requests.\n");

    return NO_ERROR;
}

BOOL WINAPI ControlCHandlerRoutine( _In_  DWORD dwCtrlType)
{
    g_threadsRunning = false;
    SetEvent(g_queueUpdated);
    g_localContext.close();
    return NO_ERROR;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    PCTSTR port = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : _T("14767");
    wstring serverAddress = _T("tcp://*:");
    serverAddress += port;
    string address = string(serverAddress.begin(), serverAddress.end());

    g_queueUpdated = CreateEvent(nullptr, FALSE, FALSE, nullptr);

    socket_t frontend(g_context, ZMQ_ROUTER);
    frontend.bind(address.c_str());
    socket_t backend(g_localContext, ZMQ_DEALER);
    backend.bind("inproc://backend");

    g_workThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(nullptr, 0, (unsigned int(__stdcall *)(PVOID)) WorkThreadStatic, nullptr, 0, (unsigned *)nullptr);
    g_zmqThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(nullptr, 0, (unsigned int(__stdcall *)(PVOID)) ZmqThreadStatic, nullptr, 0, (unsigned *)nullptr);

    printf("Listening on port: %ws\n", port);

    SetConsoleCtrlHandler(ControlCHandlerRoutine, TRUE);

    try
    {
        proxy(frontend, backend, nullptr);
    }
    catch (error_t& e)
    {
        if (e.num() != ERROR_WAIT_NO_CHILDREN)
        {
            printf("Proxy exception: %s\n", e.what());
        }
    }

    printf("Closing down...\n");
    CloseHandle(g_queueUpdated);

    frontend.unbind(address.c_str());

    frontend.close();
    backend.close();

    g_context.close();

    printf("Successfully shutdown.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Kindly specify your code-execution environment, for the **MCVE** ( to allow for a fully configured Minimum-Complete-Verifiable-Example ) ZMQ_SNDHWM, ZMQ_RCVHWM, Dual-core / Quad-core CPU, n-threads, in background processing, O/S, RAM

Comment: I've added the complete executable code (for Windows). I found no effect when trying to change the high watermarks, if you think that is the problem the please comment on howto use the high watermarks.

Windows 8 Enterprise, 64bit. Xeon E5-1650, 32GB. Visual Studio Premium 2013.

Comment: HWM details are well documented on ZeroMQ API pages.

Comment: Code-execution environment shall have no problems on scheduling multiple threads w/o waiting for resources. Did you try to increase number of **`Context()`** I/O-threads and to avoid TCP/IP encoder/decoder-phase ( going via an **`inproc:`** transport-class )?

Comment: I want to have TCP/IP encoder/decoder, otherwise it will not match the real environment. (Server and client are also separate processes, so inproc is not easily replaced.) I got no effect when changing contexts or I/Os. And strange thing is, when I try to use several threads in the server, the RTT gets even worse (significally). But I excluded that from the code for simplicity.

Comment: ZMQ is designed for bi-directional asynchronous communication, *optimized for uni-directional throughput*.  But the issues you're seeing shouldn't be there, that represents an exceptional scenario.